# How to separate beginning and ending punctuation from words using python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words with possible punctuation at their beginning and the end. I need to separate the punctuation using regex as follows:

```
sample_input = ["I", "!Go", "I'm", "call.", "exit?!"]

sample_output = ["I", "!", "Go", "I'm", "call", ".", "exit", "?", "!"]
```

The original string look like that:

```
string ="It's a mountainous wonderland decorated with ancient glaciers, breathtaking national parks and sumptuous vineyards, but behind its glossy image New Zealand is failing many of its children."
```

Does anybody have an idea, how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the circumstances. Why are you doing this? When in your script? How often.. etc..

Comment: I do it as a part of natural language processing task and in this case  taxt can be tokenized only in that way. I make web crowling, get the actuall content as a string and need to get list of the words and keep allthe punctuation in list to, to br able to reconstract the text after some preprocessing steps. All the idea that I tried delete all the punctuation at all, but i need to keep it in the list, or delete the punctuation in the middle, what i want to keep

Comment: yes... because the task is specific and i need to destinguish between end of the sentances and abbreviature, it is why i do it like this

Comment: Yes but can you instead share the string you get? I'm gonna try to remove my comments because of overflow soon.

Comment: string ="It's a mountainous wonderland decorated with ancient glaciers, breathtaking national parks and sumptuous vineyards, but behind its glossy image New Zealand is failing many of its children."

Comment: Please update question with new string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tokenize the each list item first by:

```
import re
words = ["I", "!Go", "I'm", "call.", "exit?!"]
newwords = []
for i in words:
    newwords.append(re.findall(r"[\w']+|[\W]", i))
print newwords

>>>[['I'], ['!', 'Go'], ["I'm"], ['call', '.'], ['exit', '?', '!']]
```

then getting the result by:

```
result= [item for sublist in newwords for item in sublist]
print result

>>>['I', '!', 'Go', "I'm", 'call', '.', 'exit', '?', '!']
```

You need to break each string w.r.t either `\w'` or with `\W` group to get the final list as per your desired output.
You can use this approach to write as per your code requirement.